# Building a tree view

Tags: php, mysql, tree

I'm a little stumped on this problem and I've been thinking about it for a while now. I have a table in my DB that holds a tasks. Each task can have a parent task by holding it's primary key in the parent_id field. I have no limit on how deep these tasks can be linked.

```
+-----------+-------+-----+
| Field     | Type  | Key |
+-----------+-------+-----+
| id        | int   | PRI |
| parent_id | int   | MUL |
+-------------------+-----+
```

A task without a parent_id is a "project" and all tasks can be grouped in task groups by sharing a parent task. I would now like to populate a HTML select box with all the descendant of the project.

```
Task 1
  -Task 1.1
  -Task 1.2
    -Task 1.2.1
    -Task 1.2.2
  -Task 1.3
Task 2
```

How can I go about this? I figure some sort of recursive function is in order but I can't seem to really figure how to go about it.

Any help would be greatly apprecaited. :)

Comment: google "Materialized Path" :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I highly recommend you read this article about [storing hierarchical data in a database](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/hierarchical-data-database/1).  There are two algorithms discussed there, and depending on your needs, either one of them could be appropriate.

**Adjacency List Model**

This is what you currently have.  Each node of the tree stores a reference to it's parent, and you can recursively determine the path to a node by selecting each level of a tree and iterating through the nodes.  This is simple to implement, but the drawback is that to determine a specific path to a node, recursive queries are required.  If your tree is subject to a lot of changes (ie. writes), this is a good way to go, as dynamically finding each node works well with a constantly changing tree.  If it's read-heavy, you've got some overhead in the recursion.

**Modified Preorder Tree Traversal**

My favourite, it's a very neat algorithm.  Instead of storing a reference to the parent (which you can do anyway for convenience purposes), you store a reference to the "left" and "right" nodes for each given node.  The entire path to a node can be determined in a single select query, or conversely, all the children of a node.  The algorithm is harder to implement, but it has performance benefits for read-heavy trees.  The drawback is that each time a node is moved or added, entire branches of the tree have to be recalculated, so it may not be suitable for write-heavy data sets.

Anyway, hope that article gives you some ideas.  It's a good one.

Comment: Thanks. Preorder tree traversal would have been interesting to implement but I'm too far along this project to switch now. I modified the code provided on that page to populate the select well enough.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of how you can recursively traverse your database to set up a HTML form. It is an implementation of what zombat refers to as an "Adjacency List Model".

It uses two functions: one simply to get the "top-level" elements (projects); and one recursive, to get all the children of a given element. I then use that to populate a HTML form.

```
<?php
/**
 * Fetches all the projects and returns them as an array.
 * "Projects" meaning: tasks without a parent.
 * @return array
 */
function getProjects() {
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM tree WHERE parentID IS NULL";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $results = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $results[] = $row['id'];
    }
    return $results;
}

/**
 * Fetches all tasks belonging to a specific parent.
 * Adds HTML space entities to represent the depth of each item in the tree.
 * @param int $parent_id The ID of the parent.
 * @param array $data An array containing the dat, filled in by the function.
 * @param int $current_depth Indicates the current depth of the recursion.
 * @return void
 */
function getTasks($parent_id, &$data, $current_depth=1) {
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM tree WHERE parentID = {$parent_id}";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $data[] = str_repeat('&nbsp;', $current_depth) . '- ' . $row['id'];
        getTasks($row['id'], $data, $current_depth + 1);
    }
}


/*
 * Fetch all the data and set it up so it can be used in the HTML
 */
mysql_connect('localhost', 'usr', 'pwd');
mysql_select_db('test');

// Get all the projects, adding a "-" as the initial value of the box.
$projects = array_merge(array('-'), getProjects());

// Fetch the tasks.
// If no project has been selected, just show a "please select"
$tasks = array();
if(isset($_GET['project']) && $_GET['project'] != '-') {
    getTasks($_GET['project'], $tasks);
}
else {
    $tasks = array('Select a project');
}

mysql_close();
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tree Select Example</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="get">
        <select name="project" onchange="this.parentNode.submit();">
            <?php
            foreach($projects as $_project) {
                $selected = ($_project == @$_GET['project']) ? ' selected' : '';
                echo "<option value=\"{$_project}\"{$selected}>{$_project}</option>";
            }
            ?>
        </select><br>
        <select name="tasks[]" multiple size="10">
            <?php
            foreach($tasks as $_task) {
                echo "<option value=\"{$_task}\">{$_task}</option>";
            }
            ?>
        </select><br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
    <pre><?php print_r($_GET); ?></pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

please have this function to have a treeview with you dashed -  indicator. i did for select box option.

```
function display_children($parent, $level) { 

    // retrieve all children of $parent 
    $output = "";
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM treeview_items  WHERE parent_id="'.$parent.'";'); 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
        echo "<option value='".$row['id']."'>".str_repeat('--',$level).$row['name']."</option>" ."<br>"; 
        display_children($row['id'], $level+1); 
    } 
}
```